# Good solution to filters on datagridview

Tags: c#

I'm developing an info managment system. I am using Access as my db.
Unfortunately, the datagridview doesn't support filtering rows by column content.
I'm using TableAdapter as the source and I was trying to use LINQ to SQL but it seems that the access provider is not supported. I have also heard of hibernate.

Does LTS doesn't support ACCESS?
What should I use instead?
What is the best way to use filters (filters in excel for example are perfect, because it automatically builds the list of filter options for each column).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at two separate issues:

- How do I best implement data access?

I recommend investing some time in NHibernate. LINQ to NHibernate, lazy loading, and 2nd level cached goodness all around.

and

- How do I display the data I pulled with filterable columns?

Not that I'm a huge fan, but check out ComponentOne's Flexgrid, for very flexible sorting/filtering by column functionality. (Commercial 3rd party plugin)